# Installing packages in python installed using home-brew

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

Hey everyone I installed Python3.9 on my Mac using homebrew package manager but now I do not know how to install packages to it for use

Can anyone please tell me, thanks !

Comment: Do you know what pip is?

Comment: Yes I tried it but it gave me an error which said : "Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly"

Comment: `pip install wheel` first

Comment: It says : "Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.36.2)" but still when I try downloading packages it just repeats the error

Answer (score 0):

You should first do some research on the Python virtual environment, but the final answer to your question is to use `pip install` for installing Python packages. Be aware that there are other options out there, but `pip` is the most prevalent.

Comment: See comments, OP clarified their question.

Comment: Hey Brad I am getting an error while I am trying to use pip commands

Comment: Is it happening on any package you try to install? If it's a specific package, can you say which?

Comment: Every package which needs wheels PEP 517 is behaving like that

Comment: Check to make sure you're using Python 3.9 when installing. Check your Python version with `python --version`. MacOS comes pre-installed with Python 2.7.x, so if you're not specific or in a virtual environment, it will try to use that.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed python, it has pip installed by default. pip comes with python. You can check pip version by

```
pip --version
```

OR
`pip3 --version`

Now, in order to install any other package, you can install by

```
pip install <package-name>
```

It would be better if you install a virtual environment, and install all other packages inside the virtual environment so that you can install packages according to your project requirements and with different versions.

To install virtual environment, do

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Once the virtual environment is installed, you can create your virtualenv according to your project requirement by:

`virtualenv -p python3 venv`

Here `venv` is your virtualenv name. To activate it,

```
source venv/bin/actiavte
```

Now, you can install all your required packages inside this virtualenv by `pip3 install <package-name>`. This will keep it separated from your system environment.